# How to replace fragment store first history and delete other transaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three fragments *a*, *b*, *c*
  I replace a with main activity

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.fram_container, new Fragment1(), "tag1");
transaction.commit();
```

*a* to *b*

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fram_container, new Fragment2(), "tag2");
transaction.commit();
```

and *b* to *c*

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fram_container, new Fragment3(), "tag3");
transaction.commit();
```

in *c*...

I want *c* back pressed to redirect with *a* without anything doing in *c*
  I want skip *b* in back pressed.

What can I do and how?

Comment: So you want to skip B, Then don't add it in backstack.
transaction.replace(R.id.fram_container, new Fragment3());

To back:
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(BACK_STACK_ROOT_TAG, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: in this ...first is opened but third not closed...its is overlaped with a

Answer (score 2):

Implement the below code back press

```
public void backToFragment(final Fragment fragment) {

    // go back to something that was added to the backstack
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(
            fragment.getClass().getName(), 0);
    // use 0 or the below constant as flag parameter
    // FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

}
```

Comment: ye code main activity me likhna he ya kisi fragment me ?

Comment: call to MainActivity